# how to refactor repeated code from similar tasks?

Tags: gradle

I have a set of tasks that look like this:

```
// task to run the groovy script
task('Ls', type: JavaExec) {

    environment 'gateway', props.gateway
    environment 'username', props.username
    environment 'password', props.password

    main = 'Ls'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
task('Mkdir', type: JavaExec) {

    environment 'gateway', props.gateway
    environment 'username', props.username
    environment 'password', props.password

    main = 'Mkdir'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

task('Put', type: JavaExec) {

    environment 'gateway', props.gateway
    environment 'username', props.username
    environment 'password', props.password

    main = 'Put'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

task('Example') {
    dependsOn Ls, Mkdir, Put
}
```

Is there a way that I can refactor the environment setup blocks so that that I don't have so much repeated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
['Ls', 'Mkdir', 'Put'].each { taskName ->
    task "$taskName"(type: JavaExec) {

        environment 'gateway', props.gateway
        environment 'username', props.username
        environment 'password', props.password

        main = taskName
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```